# json schema validate all array items against one or another schema

Tags: arrays, json, jsonschema

Given the following schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "definitions": {
        "worktype": {
            "blue": {
                "enum": [1, 2, 3]
            },
            "red": {
                "enum": [4, 5, 6]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I can validate an array to be either consisting of all "blue" items or "red" items like this:

```
{
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "$ref": "#/definitions/worktype/red"    // or worktype/blue
                }
}
```

But how can I validate an array to have only either "blue" or "red" worktypes, but not mixed ones?

For example:

```
[1, 2]: Valid (only blue)
[5]: Valid (only red)
[1, 6]: Invalid (mixed blue and red)
```

My first idea was using `oneOf`:

```
{
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "oneOf": [
                        {"$ref": "#/definitions/worktype/red"},
                        {"$ref": "#/definitions/worktype/blue"},
                    ]
                }
}
```

But this checks each entry for itself against the schemas, so for example `[1, 6]` is valid, too. (Afaik in this case the `oneOf` does not mean "**all** items must be valid against oneOf **together**" but "**each** item must be valid against oneOf **for itself**").

How can I write a schema for an array that either has only "blue" or "red" worktypes, but not both? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, my first idea was on the right way, but `oneOf` was simply nested one level too deep. This works like I want:

```
{
                "type": "array",
                "oneOf": [
                    {
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/worktype/red"
                        }   
                    },  
                    {
                        "items": {
                            "$ref": "#/definitions/worktype/blue"
                        }   
                    }   
                ]
}
```